# Возможно ли поменять цифры у списка <ol>?

Tags: css3, list

Кто нибудь знает как поменять цифру у списка что бы вместо 1,2,3... были свои номера?

Comment: номера по своим правилам? Через css - нет. Надо будет для каждого элемента добавлять свой номер (через тот же javascript), а уже через css можно сформировать стиль так чтобы это выглядело как требуется

Comment: уточните, что значит "поменять"? какой результат Вам нужен?

Comment: (1-первый, 2-второй) сейчас так !(17-первый 1963-второй) а нужно вот так!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, но использовать не дефолтные числа самого списка, а делать "свои" при помощи псевдоэлемента.
Т.е. вы отключаете стандартный счётчик, вешаете псевдоэлемент, выводите свои значения через `content`.

Вот например:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
}

ol li::before {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 1ch);
}

ol li:nth-child(1)::before {content: '3.';}
ol li:nth-child(2)::before {content: '-1.';}
ol li:nth-child(3)::before {content: '120.';}
ol li:nth-child(4)::before {content: '32.';}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Так же можете воспользоваться [счётчиками CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

---

Ещё можно взять возможность правила `content` работать с атрибутами CSS - [подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/css/attr)

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

ol li {
  position: relative;
}

ol li::before {
  content: attr(data-num)'.';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(100% + 1ch);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li data-num="3">Item 1</li>
  <li data-num="-1">Item 2</li>
  <li data-num="120">Item 3</li>
  <li data-num="32">Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 4):

Менять дефолтное положение элементов списка можно с помощью `order`, предварительно задав списку `display: flex`, а всем элементам - самый большой номер, который есть в Вашем списке:

```css
ol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
li {
  order: 10;
}
li:nth-of-type(6) {
  order: 1;
}
li:nth-of-type(3) {
  order: 2;
}
li:nth-of-type(9) {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```